# how to select some point with specificals coordinates?

Tags: r, dataframe

My data set is:

```
 mydata <- data.frame(
  x1= as.factor(1:3), 
  x2= as.factor (4:6), 
  x3= as.factor(7:9), 
  x4= as.factor (2:7), 
  x5= as.factor(1:6), 
  fx= seq(0,600,len= 600),
  time= seq(0,1,len=600)
  )%>%
    group_by(x1, x2, x3, x4,x5)
```

I want to select the points that have the coordinates (time, fx),
  that match to the first point of time , the last point of time, 
  the point in which there is the min(Fx), and half
  of intervals points

```
(( ( time[[min(fx)]] - time[[1]]/2)+ time [[1]])
```

and

`(time[[length(time)]]-time[[min(fx)]]/2)+time[[min(fx)]]))`

is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `filter`, not `select` (you want to reduce the rows, not the columns). Then, you want to filter based on multiple conditions, so use the logical `or` operator, which is `|`. Lastly, to help dplyr along, when doing the `min()` arguments, include the full dataframe name. This should get you started:

`mydata %>% filter(time == min(mydata$time)|
                    time == max(mydata$time)|
                    fx==min(mydata$fx))`

I didn't add the other two intervals because I'm not fully sure what you wanted, but perhaps this should help you enough?